# How to get data from first table only after joining 2 tables

Tags: oracle, performance, optimization

We have 2 table. The first table is employee and second table is books.

```
CREATE TABLE  EMPLOYEE
   (    "EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER(19,0) not null,
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(256),
     CONSTRAINT "ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("EMPLOYEE_ID") ENABLE
   );
   
   CREATE TABLE  BOOKS
   (    "ID" VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "BOOKNAME" VARCHAR2(256),
  "EMP_ID" NUMBER(19,0) not null,
     CONSTRAINT "BOOK_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE,
     CONSTRAINT "EMP_FK1" FOREIGN KEY (EMP_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE
   );
insert into employee  values (1, 'James');
insert into employee  values (2, 'John');

insert into BOOKS  values (1, 'JAVA', 1);
insert into BOOKS  values (2, 'CProgramming', 1);
insert into BOOKS  values (3, 'JSP', 1);
insert into BOOKS  values (4, 'Accountancy', 2);
insert into BOOKS  values (5, 'History', 2);
insert into BOOKS  values (6, 'Geography', 2);
```

In the above code , there could be lots of books and we do not want to load the books rows. Therefore , we are using rownum in where clause.
Is there a way we can use rownum and get the right count from employee table only, though we do a join ?

```
select distinct b.EMP_ID from EMPLOYEE e , Books b
where e.EMPLOYEE_ID= b.EMP_ID
and rownum <= 2;

select count(distinct b.EMP_ID) from EMPLOYEE e , Books b
where e.EMPLOYEE_ID= b.EMP_ID
and rownum <= 2;

**Expected output:**


     EMP_ID
----------
         1
         2
```

Comment: and what is expected output??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`books` table must be involved, somehow - I'd suggest `exists`.

```
SQL> select * from employee order by employee_id;

EMPLOYEE_ID NAME
----------- ---------------
          1 James
          2 John
          3 Littlefoot   --> no rows for this EMPLOYEE_ID in BOOKS table
             
SQL> select * from books order by emp_id;

ID BOOKNAME                 EMP_ID
-- -------------------- ----------
1  JAVA                          1
2  CProgramming                  1
3  JSP                           1
4  Accountancy                   2
5  History                       2
6  Geography                     2

6 rows selected.
```

To find employees whose IDs exist in BOOKS table, run

```
SQL> select e.employee_id
  2  from employee e
  3  where exists (select null
  4                from books b
  5                where b.emp_id = e.employee_id
  6               );

EMPLOYEE_ID
-----------
          1
          2              --> as expected, no EMPLOYEE_ID = 3 in result set

SQL>
```